# Node setup for combining baked Diffuse Indirect, Direct, and Color passes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I am trying to combine the *Diffuse Indirect*, *Diffuse Direct*, and *Diffuse Color* passes after baking.

*Diffuse Indirect*, and *Diffuse Direct* are fine When using the *add* shader, but I can't get the It to output the Color using the node setup below.

[image: Diffuse setup]

Answer (score 2):

There is problem with you nodes. You have a color mix node after the BSDF Shader nodes. That does not work.
Using the same type of setup with three images for Indirect, Direct, and Color this is how the nodes should look. Notice the indirect and direct are added together. Then the color is mixed in with another color mix node set to *value* with the *Fac* set to `.5`.
[image: nodes]

All color operations happen before the Shader nodes. After the first shader node only other shader nodes can be used.